# comparing survey responses

Tags: spss, survey

I have requested 30 participants to answer the same question about 100 images: "How easy is it for you to recognize this image?" on a scale from 0 to 100, where 0 is easy and 100 is difficult.

I want to 1) eliminate extreme scores, so the closer they are to 100, the more unfavourable these images will be to me. 2) I would like to identify participants with extreme scores, so for instance if they were bored and they have different scores than the rest I would like to identify these.

Would I do a simple descriptive analysis to see whether some participants have higher means than the rest (or look at standard deviations)? Also, how can I compare the scores on the images, would a graph with frequencies do the trick?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's not just about standard deviation for each question, but I would need to find a test to see if there are statistically significant differences between questions. Of course I would like to rule out outliers (which I can deal with), but I need to compare the results for each question.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your message. It is related to stats, I'm not worried about the software, but more so about the theoretical approach to solving the statistical question.

Comment: Then you may want to edit your Q to emphasize the statistical issues that you need clarified & deemphasizing the software-specific aspects.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of doing this? Why do you want to identify images of middling difficulty & participants of middling ability?

Comment: I'm more concerned with identifying images which have the most extreme scores (closer to 100) out of all of them and to see how this relates to the average scores of the others. (Also, to eliminate participants who have extreme scores, so for instance if the averages are low for all images and one participant deviates from the average, then I would like to identity him/her).

Comment: Fair enough, but *why*? Let's say you've done that already. Now want do you want to do with this information / the images & participants?

Comment: That's a pilot for one of my experiments, where I will show these images. It's a bit more complicated. These images that I've shown are actually pairs (one red and one green which have been randomized). Once I identify the extreme ones, I will follow-up with t-tests to ensure that the same image in red doesn't get different scores than the one in green. In the actual experiment I need these to be easy to recognize because I'm looking at how quickly participants react to them and want to decrease any confounding factors.

Comment: Confounding factors would include hard to recognize images because these would slow down participants and would interfere with what I'm measuring: how visual popup images (distractions) interfere with participant reaction time to these images and categorization.